# How to concatenate two columns and update the csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

In Excel, I would be able to use something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)
```

(User flood fill's this down the spreadsheet, and then simply deletes A and B, lastly you move results to A)

End Result is expected to have A and B columns merged into one column (A) and separated by one space.

In Python here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            print("Adding merged COL1/COL2 into one column for every row...")
            wtr.writerow(r+[r[0] + ' ' + r[1]])
            print("Deleting COL1/COL2 columns from every row...")
            del r[0]
            del r[0]
            wtr.writerow( r )
    result.close();
```

Although, the above code does properly merge two columns and append a column to the end of the file, it does not properly delete the first two rows once it is finished, I believe this is because wtr.writerow has already been called. Also, I am unsure how to move the column to the left (back to A), since it always appends to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So every row you're reading from (and writing to) csv is a list, right? So take another step or two and create the list you want, then write it.

e.g.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = [' '.join([row[0], row[1]])] + row[2:]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Also, I doubt you need to read/write binary ('rb', 'wb') from a csv.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: With a sample csv of e.g. "1;2;3;4" using your provided code I get "list index out of range" pointing to the "row[1]". Any idea what might be causing this?

>>Answer: python expected "," and got ";"....

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `writerow` twice in that loop. I don't think you want that - writing the merged columns and then the others separately? No.

You can simply join the merged columns to the *start* of the rows, and *slice off* the old rows:

```
wtr.writerow([r[0] + ' ' + r[1]] + r[2:])
#            ^<- merged rows are added to the start
#                                   ^<- slice off old A1 and B1
```

You won't need the `del` statements any longer, and one call to `writerow` inserts your modified *row*:

```
import csv 

with open("test.csv","rb") as source, open("result","wb") as result:
    rdr = csv.reader(source)
    wtr = csv.writer(result)
    for r in rdr:
        wtr.writerow([r[0] + ' ' + r[1]] + r[2:])
```

Also, note that you can put multiple expressions after a `with` statement, like I did above.

---

Finally, you don't need to manually close the file - `result.close()`. The `with` context already *manages* that.

Comment: Using split is a good idea, I was also unsure if close() was needed. Thanks!